# Calculations in Core Data Managed Objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, data-modeling, nsfetchrequest

I have modeled a company's financial data by **subclassing Core Data Managed Objects** (please refer to the data model screenshot below).

For each company IBCompany (only partly shown) there are 1:n **financial periods** (**IBEstPeriod**), which are defined by its year and period number (for example 2012/1). Each financial period has 1:n **financial data** items, for instance *Revenue*, which is stored in the attribute *type* in **IBEstPeriod** and each of these financial data item consists of multiple values, which are stored in **IBConsHistory** as *curr*, *ma1*, *ma2*, etc), for instance 100, 105, 107.

Comment: I'm still unclear about exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you might want to look into transient properties and custom getter methods. Also, are you using core data aggregate functions on these values, or just using them one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this new value will be based on existing data, you should calculate it as you need it.  The main reason for this is to refrain from creating dependencies.  That is, if you store this calculated value, you will have to recalculate it each time you use any value from which this new value is based.